# Blank pages with a message

Tags: xetex, blank-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make pages which were “intentionally left blank”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/how-do-i-make-pages-which-were-intentionally-left-blank)

I want to produce the effects as in a conventional book, wherein you have `\cleardoublepage` with a message like "This page has been intensionally left blank."

Is there an easy way to do this in LaTeX? I want to do this with every even numbered page left by `\cleardoublepage`...

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I make pages which were "intentionally left blank"?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1727)

Comment: @ienissei: thx..it is...didn't find in search....can be closed...I guess...