# Modify style of \cleardoublepage

Tags: article

I'm looking for a solution to put on empty pages generated by `cleardoublepage` a centered text "empty page". What I want is, that all sections open right and I there added a empty page, this page should marked with "empty page".

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,
               notitlepage,cleardoublepage=empty,
               ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            bindingoffset=1cm,margin=2cm,
            includeheadfoot,
%            top=25mm, bottom=25mm,
%            headheight=15mm, headsep=7mm
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} % Load the TS1-encoding e.g. through textcomp 
\usepackage{verbatim, environ}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\section{eins}
\blindtext
\cleardoublepage
\section{zwei}
\blindtext
\cleardoublepage
\section{drei}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\Blindtext
\cleardoublepage
\section{vier}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

---

---

### 1st modified exsample

In attention to your comments here a new example. This shows how it should look like. Only the mark "empty page" is missing. The functionality of cleardoublepage and the head and foot have to be untouched.

The functionality I mean is: cleardoublepage only insert a empty page if the last section ends on an odd page (old section: odd page -> cleardoublepage: empty even page -> next section: odd page). In case of a section ends on an even page cleardoublepage hast no effects. (old section: odd page -> cleardoublepage: no page inserted -> next section: odd page)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,
               notitlepage,
               ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            bindingoffset=1cm,margin=2cm,
            includeheadfoot,
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} % Load the TS1-encoding e.g. through textcomp 
\usepackage{verbatim, environ}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\makeatletter
   \def\ps@vakatseite{%
     \vspace*{\fill}
     \centering This page would be intentionally left blank if we would not wish to inform about that.
      \vspace{\fill}
   }
\makeatother

\newcommand{\newsection}[1]
   {{\cleardoublepage}
    \section{#1}
   }

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead[OL]{\scshape\leftmark}
 \fancyhead[ER]{\scshape\leftmark}
 \fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
 \fancyfoot[OL]{\scshape\leftmark}
 \fancyfoot[ER]{\scshape\leftmark}
 \fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\newsection{eins}
\blindtext
\newsection{zwei}
\blindtext[3]
\newsection{drei}
\blindtext[8]
\newsection{vier}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

If I use

```
\clearpage{\pagestyle{vakatseite}\cleardoublepage}
```

I will get one or two empty pages with one marked page. I want zero or one page instead...
[image: printed example]

---

---

### Final Code

Thanks to Harish Kumar. This solution is fully what I want :)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,
               notitlepage,
               ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            bindingoffset=1cm,margin=2cm,
            includeheadfoot,
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} % Load the TS1-encoding e.g. through textcomp 
\usepackage{verbatim, environ}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\def\emptypage@emptypage{%
    \hbox{}%
     \vspace*{\fill}
     \begin{center}
     This page would be intentionally left blank\\ if we would not wish to inform about that.
     \end{center}
     \vspace{\fill}
     \newpage%    
}%
\def\cleardoublepage{%
        \clearpage%
        \if@twoside%
            \ifodd\c@page%
                % do nothing
            \else%
                \emptypage@emptypage%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    }%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\newsection}[1]
   {\cleardoublepage
    \section{#1}
   }

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead[OL]{\scshape\leftmark}
 \fancyhead[ER]{\scshape\leftmark}
 \fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
 \fancyfoot[OL]{\scshape\leftmark}
 \fancyfoot[ER]{\scshape\leftmark}
 \fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\newsection{eins}
\blindtext
\newsection{zwei}
\blindtext[3]
\newsection{drei}
\blindtext[7]
\newsection{vier}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/how-do-i-make-pages-which-were-intentionally-left-blank help?

Comment: What are `openright`, `cleardoublepage=empty` and `notitlepage` supposed to do? I didn't think (1) applied to `article`. I can't find (2) in any of the `base` files for LaTeX, and I thought (3) was default for `article`. EDIT: I guess (2) is from `koma-script` but I don't think it will have any effect here. Indeed, latex complains that the following global options are unused: `[openright,cleardoublepage=empty]`.

Comment: Are you bound to use the `article` document class or would you be willing to use another one (`scrartcl` or `memoir`, for example)?

Comment: @cfr
openright - comes by a further test - it's unnecessary; 
notitlepage - I need for the abstract; 
cleardoublepage=empty - set the pagestyle on clearpages -> that's the part I want to improve

Comment: *Not with `article`.* `cleardoublepage=empty` does zilch with `article`. `notitlepage` is default anyway. *With `article`.* If you are getting different results, you are either loading additional packages which make use of those global options or you are using a different class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the update to the OP, I think if you add these in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[draw=orange,fill=blue!50!green,scale=4,rotate=45,anchor=center,rounded corners=2em,text=magenta] at (current page.center) {Empty Page};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\makeatletter
\def\emptypage@emptypage{%
    \hbox{}%
    \blankpage%
    \newpage%    
}%
\def\cleardoublepage{%
        \clearpage%
        \if@twoside%
            \ifodd\c@page%
                % do nothing
            \else%
                \emptypage@emptypage%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    }%
\makeatother
```

you will get the desired result. You can replace `\blankpage` as per you wish.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,
               notitlepage,
               ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            bindingoffset=1cm,margin=2cm,
            includeheadfoot,headheight=15pt
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} % Load the TS1-encoding e.g. through textcomp
\usepackage{verbatim, environ}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[draw=orange,fill=blue!50!green,scale=4,rotate=45,anchor=center,rounded corners=2em,text=magenta] at (current page.center) {Empty Page};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\makeatletter
\def\emptypage@emptypage{%
    \hbox{}%
    \blankpage%
    \newpage%    
}%
\def\cleardoublepage{%
        \clearpage%
        \if@twoside%
            \ifodd\c@page%
                % do nothing
            \else%
                \emptypage@emptypage%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    }%
\makeatother


\newcommand{\newsection}[1]
   {{\cleardoublepage}
    \section{#1}
   }

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead[OL]{\scshape\leftmark}
 \fancyhead[ER]{\scshape\leftmark}
 \fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
 \fancyfoot[OL]{\scshape\leftmark}
 \fancyfoot[ER]{\scshape\leftmark}
 \fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\newsection{eins}
\blindtext
\newsection{zwei}
\blindtext[3]
\newsection{drei}
\blindtext[8]
\newsection{vier}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want these blank pages to have no header and footer add `\thispagestyle{empty}` just before `\blankpage` in the definition of `\emptypage@emptypage`:

```
\def\emptypage@emptypage{%
    \hbox{}%
    \thispagestyle{empty}   %% or any page style
    \blankpage%
    \newpage%    
}%
```

Comment: This is on the right way, but this removes my footline and the functionality of cleardoublepage. This create only a empty page if an section (in my case) ends on an odd page, so that a empty page filled in on the next even page and the next section starts on an odd page...

Comment: I add a new example in the post above. And a new try of explanation...

Comment: How can I insert a printed tex-example like you?

Comment: it is uploaded above