# Extra blank pages inserted when using \cleardoublepage and \newgeometry

Tags: geometry, blank-page

Using a `report` class with the `twoside` and `openright` options, I've defined a function, `\mycentered[1]`, to display a vertically and horizontally aligned (at the center of the page) quote before the table of contents.

The text gets correctly displayed, and when `\cleardoublepage` is used before `\tableofcontents` just a blank page is inserted. But, if I use `\newgometry` (provided by the `geometry` package) between the page clearing and the table of contents, three blank pages are inserted. However, if I replace `\mycentered` with some text, those pages are not inserted. How can avoid those two extra pages being added?

In the following MWE the pagestyle is also changed just to show that the aditional blank pages are introduced *after* the explicit `\cleardoublepage`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\newcommand\mycentered[1]{\topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}{\centering#1\par}\vspace*{\fill}}

\def\mytextblock{
This is some text

with several paragraphs
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\mycentered{\mytextblock}
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{plain}
\newgeometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}

\end{document}
```

---

I've tried removing `\topskip0pt` and the blank pages issue is solved. But the content is not really centered, since some space is put in the top. It is not noticeable with not very long quotes, but the following image shows the difference if used to vertically center bigger blocks. On the left hand side the result with `\topskip0pt` is shown, and on the right hand side the result without it is overlaid.

[image]

Comment: Remove `\topskip0pt` and you are on track.

Comment: I've just edited to add a picture with the difference when removing it. I'd prefer not to use `tikz` as you answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161383/modify-style-of-cleardoublepage/161386#161386), if possible. If not, I'll go for it.

Comment: Use `\topskip=0pt` only locally for the selected page. I. e. enclose the body of `\mycentered` to braces: `\newcommand\mycentered[1]{{\topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}{\centering#1\par}\vspace*{\fill}}}`

Comment: I tried, but it won't compile. Anyway, I found a solution (see answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly compensating the `\topskip`, instead of setting it to `0pt`, solved the problem and no extra space is put at the top.

```
\newcommand\th@centered[1]{\hbox{}\vspace*{-\topskip}\vspace*{\fill}{\centering#1\par}\vspace{\fill}}
```