# How to make "This page intentionally left blank." in KOMA script

Tags: tikz-pgf, koma-script

This question is sequel to question

[How do I make pages which were "intentionally left blank"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/how-do-i-make-pages-which-were-intentionally-left-blank)

The accepted solution there

```
\documentclass[openright]{scrbook}
\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
\vspace*{\fill}
\centering This page would be intentionally left blank if we would not wish to inform about that.
\vspace{\fill}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\blankpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Text
\chapter{First chapter}
\end{document}
```

does insert blank page warning, but only `\mainmatter`.  `\frontmatter`, `\appendix` and `\backmatter` do not have blank page warning.

Is there any way to tweak this solution so it would produce blank page warning for the whole document?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With `scrbook` the command to redefine is `\cleardoubleoddstandardpage`

```
\documentclass[openright]{scrbook}

\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
  \par\vspace*{\fill}%
  {\centering This page would be intentionally left blank
   if we would not wish to inform about that.\par}
  \vspace{\fill}%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cleardoubleoddstandardpage}{%
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
    \else
      \blankpage
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \newpage
      \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can define a special pagestyle for those pages using the package `scrlayer` and the KOMA option `cleardoublepage=<pagestyle>`

```
\documentclass[open=right]{scrbook}

\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
  \par\vspace*{\fill}%
  {\centering This page would be intentionally left blank
   if we would not wish to inform about that.\par}
  \vspace{\fill}%
}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    foreground,
    textarea,
    contents=\blankpage
  ]{blankpage.fg}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{blank}{blankpage.fg}
\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=blank}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\end{document}
```

This will also work if a blank page is inserted by a `\cleardoubleevenpage` command or if you switch to `open=left`.