# Page Number Disappearing with openright

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I am using such a document class

```
\documentclass[11pt%
,a4paper%
,headsepline%
,headinclude=false%
,footinclude=false%
,twoside=true%
,cleardoublepage=empty%
,appendixprefix%
,numbers=noenddot%
,bibliography=totoc%
,listof=totoc%
,openany%
,open = right%                              ,
]{scrbook}
```

The problem is about the black pages that open = right gives after every chapter that they are not numbered... and I want the blanks to be numbered too

Thanks in advance,

QD

Comment: They are numbered, you just don't see it. You want it that way: `cleardoublepage=empty`

Comment: @Johannes_B hey yeah I thought so too but I commented it out that did not help

Comment: `cleardoublepage=empty` is default. Use `cleardoublepage=plain` to get the page numbers on pages inserted by `\cleardoublepage`.

Comment: Because that is the default behaviour, use `current` instead of `empty`. Wherre did you get the template from?

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks to you too , the template is from my institute

Comment: If it is from your institute, maybe there shouldn't be a pagenumber showing and the option is set on purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a KOMA-Script class (or the package `scrextend` together with a standard class) there is an option to set the page style of blank pages:

```
cleardoublepage=<page style name>
```

The default value of this option is `empty`.

To change the layout of the blank pages you can decide which page style they should use. If there should be only the page number

```
cleardoublepage=plain
```

could be a good decision. It is also possible to define an own page style for those pages. As an example see [How to make “This page intentionally left blank.” in KOMA script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205545/43317)

If the blank pages should have the same page style as the pages before use

```
cleardoublepage=current
```

In that case the blank pages behave in the same way as the would do with a standard class.

See the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) for additional informations.

---

Note that it does not make sense to use `openany` followed by `open=right`: `openany` sets `open=any` and `open=right` changes the `open` option back to its default value for `scrbook`.