# Redefining "ClearDoublePage" ruins subfigures

Tags: floats, lyx, subfloats, preamble, blank-page

I found some solution to add a "This page intentionally left blank" text on clear pages by redefining things in preamble, but it somehow messes up with subfloats.
If I have a subfigure / subtable, when trying to View the document there are errors:

```
You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
Missing $ inserted.
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
Missing glyphs!
Use of \sf doesn't match its definition.
...
```

and more.

I am using a KOMA-Script Book document class, and the preamble looks like this:

```
\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
  \par\vspace*{0.25\textheight}%
  {\centering \emph{This page intentionally left blank.}\par}
  \vspace{\fill}%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cleardoubleoddstandardpage}{%
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
    \else
  \blankpage
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \newpage
      \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

[The LyX document file available here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxzpjwbg78s9b2l/temp.lyx?dl=0)
System configuration:
LyX Version 2.2.3
Windows 10 x64
MiKTeX 2.9

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please include your minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), to your question and avoid links (which could be broken in the future). Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You are using a KOMA-Script class. So maybe the following helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205545

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, esdd's sugestion worked.

After deleting this part

```
\renewcommand*{\cleardoubleoddstandardpage}{%
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
    \else
  \blankpage
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \newpage
      \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

the document will compile.