# “This page intentionally left blank” after \part

Tags: blank-page

I sometimes use the following snippet to add a note to empty pages saying that they were intentionally left blank --- I'm not 100% sure where exactly it's from, but similar snippets can be found in various questions and answers, e. g. in [How do I make pages which were “intentionally left blank”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1727/):

```
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\mbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
This page intentionally left blank.
\end{center}
\vspace{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\mbox{}\newpage\fi
\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

It turns out that when using the `book` document class, empty pages inserted by `\part` do not carry this notice, so I'd like to share what I did to add the same notice to those, in the hopes that others may find it helpful.

Comment: Can a page be considered blank if a phrase, e.g., the phrase "This page intentionally left blank", is written to it? ;-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez: Yes, with the exception of said phrase :)

Comment: @Ingmar Then the statement should be "This page intentionally left blank except for this phrase."   Btw: How about a sheet of paper, one side holding "The statement on the other side of this sheet of paper is true", the other side holding "The statement on the other side of this sheet of paper is false" ?   :-)

Comment: No need to state the obvious ... This is not to create a paradox or satisfy some perverted sense of formal logic, but to let people know that yes, there really is supposed to be an (almost) blank page there, and no mistake. IBM famously did this in all their manuals. You can still see it occasionally, although it's usually (and euphemistically) called "For your notes" these days ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to redefine `\@endpart` (which is used internally by `\part`) in an analogous manner by replacing the `\null` it contains with the relevant code from the above snippet:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage\if@twoside \if@openright
\mbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
This page intentionally left blank.
\end{center}
\vspace{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage\fi\fi
\if@tempswa\twocolumn\fi}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report` and `article`) then this
will do it for you.

```
% partpageprob.tex  SE 586270
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\nopartblankpage  % no blank page after a \part
\part{A PART}
 % go to a special page after \part, putting text on the skipped page
\movetooddpage[\thispagestyle{empty}%
  \vfil \begin{center}This page intentionally left blank\end{center}\vfil]
Some text
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might find `memoirs` methods of moving to another page useful in general.